# How to avoid screen reloading when switching between screens in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am building a mobile application that includes creating a drawer to switch between screens. Assuming I have 3 screens A, B, and C, how can I make it so that when I select screen A, it only loads data for the first time, and subsequent times I open screen A, it still retains the data without reloading? Similarly for screens B and C.

Are there ways to achieve this in Flutter? I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of the flutter or which libs you are using for, but anyway I think you can do like this .Use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

```
class ScreenA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenAState createState() => _ScreenAState();
}

class _ScreenAState extends State<ScreenA> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  // Add this line to preserve state
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  // Your screen A code goes here
  // ...
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // Don't forget to call super.build.
    return Scaffold(
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

// same you will have for the B and c